# Why does this Python3 module appear to perform a relative import of itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

If I create a module named 'json.py' with the following contents:

```
#! python
import json as _json
JSONDecoder = _json.JSONDecoder
```

..shouldn't the 'import json as _json' statement perform an absolute import, and therefore provide the python standard-lib JSON module?

..instead, if I execute or import this module, I get:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.0
$ python relative_import/json.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "relative_import/json.py", line 3, in 
    import json as _json
  File "/home/silver/Projects/relative_import/json.py", line 6, in 
    JSONDecoder = _json.JSONDecoder
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecoder'
$
```

..which shows that 'json' is importing itself (a relative import).  ..I imagine I'm missing something -- python's import system has always made natural and intuitive sense to me, but in this case I'm lost.

**Edit:** I'm using python 3.4

**Edit:** For anyone interested, this is what occurred:
I have a package which includes a module called 'json', which replaces the system 'json'.  This is fine (IMO), however, I also started a script that was in the same package folder (temporarily) but not meant to ultimately be a part of the same module.  Thus, the following occurred:

- I run my script, packagename/foo.py
- python adds packagename folder to sys.path
- foo.py imports packagename.json
- packagename.json imports json (which would normally be the system json)
- first entry on sys.path is the packagename folder, and 'json' is imported from there
- my json.py continues loading after the import, and runs into errors (because it's dealing with itself, not the system json module)

Solution:  Move the script to my package's 'bin' folder, or, if I want it to be a part of the package proper, use `python -m packagename.foo`

Thank you, @Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* doing an absolute import.

The directory the *main script* lives in is added to `sys.path`, and as a result the first `json` found is your script. You are running `python relative_import/json.py` and Python thus adds `relative_import/` to `sys.path`.

Note that the main script is named `__main__`, so `import json` does import the script file as a separate, new module object. Your code is in effect loaded twice.

See the [*Interface options* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options):

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of `sys.path`, and the file is executed as the `__main__` module.

Comment: Huh.  I was had thought that the only way to get a module from within your current package was to use `from . import y` or (if the package is available globally) `from mymodule import y`.  Thank you, this is the missing detail I needed.

Comment: @BrianVisel: you don't have a package here though. The top-level script is *never* a package. Use the `-m` switch if you want to use a package as a script instead.

Comment: True.  And here's an interesting thought -- if someone doesn't remove the `.py` extension from their script, and their script goes into a `bin/` folder somewhere, then it would be importable by other scripts, thereby causing them to execute code they did not intend.  Of course, if you're permitting that to be installed on your system, there are already issues with your security.

Comment: ..so, is there a canonical way to import a system module via a script of the same name?  ..one could always remove the directory of `__main__.__file__` from sys.path, or simply pop the first item off of sys.path, but is there some other way to do this?

Comment: @BrianVisel: only with a lot of pain. Basically, you don't name your scripts something that'll mask a library.

Comment: @BrianVisel: you'd have to use the low-level functionality of the [`importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) to bypass the normal `sys.path` import lookup semantics.

Comment: *nod* It is general bad practice to name a script in a manner that is identical to a system library.  However, naming a module in a package identically to a system library is (IMO) not bad practice -- which, although not included in my example above, was the case.

Comment: @BrianVisel: sure, but in that case you shouldn't try and run files in the package as a script. :-)

Comment: Which was exactly my problem, because I had simply edited it there when starting, planning on moving it to a bin folder later -- not knowing that the folder of the executable would be prepended to sys.path, interfering with the import.  I thought this was something that changed with the absolute import changes moving from Python2 to Python3, but I was mistaken.